# How to prevent users from uploading the same file (image) multiple times?

Tags: media, nodes

I have a content type, Image, which allows users to add an image using Drupal 7's built-in image field.  I would like to automatically prevent users from adding the exact same image (same filename, same size) if possible.  Is there any way to prevent duplicate file uploads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now a module for this, the [File Hash](https://drupal.org/project/filehash) module.  Many thanks to Jimajamma for outlining his approach, which allowed me to find this module via Google.

As shown in [this thread](https://drupal.org/node/1910372), the module can currently be used to disable duplicate file uploads globally.

Comment: How to achieve this in D6 ? any idea !!!

Comment: See Jimajamma's answer.  A new module will need to be written (or backport the File Hash module).

Comment: backport means ???

Comment: Port the File Hash module from Drupal 7 back to Drupal 6.  Drupal modules are specific to the major release they target (6, 7, 8, etc.), so to use a Drupal 7 module on Drupal 6, a conversion will have to be performed.  How difficult this is depends on the complexity of the module.  A good place to start is to open a feature request in the module's issue queue for a D6 backport and see what the maintainer says.

Answer (score 5):

In pseudo/quick code, this is how I would approach it.  In a custom module...

1. Create a table in the db, with two columns, fid and md5.
2. Each time you create a file, check if the md5() of whatever you consider unique is in that db, eg:

   a.  select fid from TABLE where md5 = ab3783ea6c83bcd9383eef778

   b.  if fid then oops, there already appears to be file blah blah blah

   c.  otherwise
3. Store that file's fid and md5() in that table.

You could put all this logic in the validation hook when you are creating the image content.  You could even set up roles that are able to override it, etc.

Now, to the md5()ing of things.

1. Filename is easily changed and I don't think it is really sent to drupal anyway--but instead crafted there after the fact--so do you really want to use it?
2. Content of the file might be a better approach.

So, md5 could be populated with a quick md5_file(PATHTOFILE).

Now, let's say you wanted to have an option of doing this system wide or per user, eg, you don't want one user uploading multiple copies of one image or you want to have only one exact image uploaded systemwide.

Just add another column uid to the table above and check it as well, eg:

select fid from TABLE where md5 = ... and uid = $user->uid

Anyway, these are just my quick thoughts after the morning's first espresso here in D6land.  Maybe D7 has some of this already built into it and I am once again reinventing that wheel :)

Comment: This is essentially the approach I was about to write up.  If you make the MD5 the PK of the table, the logic becomes a bit simpler because you can't INSERT duplicates.

Comment: I agree on the PK if you don't want to also allow/do it by uid.

Comment: @MPD I would make fid from file_managed PK here, for consistency. Schema supports 'unique keys'.